# UNIX: is possible to bypass exit codes of unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I´m writing some **Shell** code and, for some logic of programming, I need to do some **returns** with *negative* numbers. This is:

```
if condition ; then
   return -1
else 
   return -2
fi
```

Nevertheless, I get errors when using negative numbers, maybe because: `Unix exit statuses are restricted to values 0-255, the range of an unsigned 8-bit integer.` (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Unix)

Is there a way to bypass this? (I know that I could use another return numbers)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm curoius what would lead you to need a negative exit code anyway...

Comment: The standard of the company. They use **negative codes** for errors and **positive for success**. And they want it **that way** in Shell :/

Comment: couldn't you just set an "err" parameter and look for it when the code returns. If "err" is set, treat the return value as the negative value of return.

Comment: LOL!  (just filling here to have the 15 chars!)

Comment: Tanktalus is dead on here.  Your company policy is in conflict with standard conventions.  If they want to work on non-unix machines, that's great.  But if they are working in a unix-like environment, it is insane not to follow the standard unix conventions.  You should consider this a serious issue.

Comment: Well, they are setting up an UNIX server and I´m rewriting some functions to Shell (which is good, it takes few lines). Definitively, I will tell them this. Nevertheless is a big bank and I´m not very sure of their receptiveness. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but the Unix standard for shell scripting is exit 0 for success and exit non-zero for non-success.

The best you can do is capture return values and use them as you want, i.e.

```
myfunc () {  
    printf -- "$1" "\n"
    if (( ${1:-0} == 0 )) ; then
       return 0
    else
       return 1
    fi   
}

var=$(myfunc -2)
print var=${var}

#output
var=-2
```

Not what your overlords want to hear, but refer them to the [Posix Standards](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/toc.htm).

Also FYI, `$()` is called command substitution. You will see people also implement command sub with paired back ticks '`cmd`', but use the `$( cmd )`, unless you are using original borne shell coding on Sun/AIX or other heritage vendor platforms OR you are required to create code that is completely backwards (with the emphasis on backwards!) compatible.

`$()` is nice because you can nest them as much as you need, i.e.

```
 $( cmd1 $( cmd2 $( cmd..n ) ) )
```

According the New Kornshell Programming Language (ISBN-10: 0131827006, 1995!) backticks are deprecated.

Note that either type of command substitution is creating a sub-shell to run the command, and then 'substitute in' the results into your command line.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I think this is an elegant solution. I will implement it under the hood

Comment: @kani This solution (+1, btw) does not conform to your company's stated policy.  The output of the function may be a string that evaluates to a negative integer when parsed by strtol, but the return value of the myfunc is always positive 1 (even when it fails!)

Comment: @WilliamPursell : Yes, thanks (on both accounts ;-)), I deliberately put in an arbitrary return value to illustrate that there was no way (as per the error message @kani got in the first place) to return a negative value. Given @kani 's example code `if ... return -1 ; else return -2 ... fi` I'm assuming that they understand returning different codes for different cases. I've edited the example so a success emits returns zero (per Unix stds!) and non-zero for error. Thanks for your comment and good luck to all.